# django filter older than day(s)?

Tags: django

The day is the number a user will input to get the result that is older than (days from user input). For example, if user inputs 32 days, they will get the results that are older than 30 days.

A quick try-out:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    entered = models.DateTimeField()

>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> Entry(entered = datetime.now()).save()
>>> Entry.objects.filter(entered__lte = datetime.now())
[<Entry: Entry object>]
>>> Entry.objects.filter(entered__gte = datetime.now())
[]
>>> Entry.objects.filter(entered__gte = datetime.now(), entered__lte=datetime(2009,11,1,0,0))
[<Entry: Entry object>]
```

My problem and my trying

```
xxxx__day__lte.
```

`last_contact_filled` input from input field

```
for day_filter in xrange(1,int(last_contact_filled)+1):
                qdict['last_contact__day']=day_filter
```

What's the best way to do this in Django to filter by day(s) in my case?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Something like this would work for you:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
how_many_days = 30
MyObject.objects.filter(entered__lte=datetime.now()-timedelta(days=how_many_days))
```

Comment: Do prevent the native time error (RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField xxx.created_at received a naive datetime (2016-05-01 11:31:59.768065) while time zone support is active) 

you should import djangos timezone now function:

from django.utils.timezone import now

Comment: Is it greater than or less than? Don't you need to use `entered__lte=....` there?

Comment: @Rehmat, agree, it should be `__lte` as we're filtering *older* objects. The accepted answer is wrong

Answer (score 22):

we can use Django timezone.now() with timedelta

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.utils import timezone
time_threshold = timezone.now() - timedelta(days=7)
Entry.objects.filter(entered__gte=time_threshold)
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a `timedelta(-30)` to the `datetime` in the filter.

Comment: dont understand whant you want me to add ,where to add?

Comment: `datetime.now() + timedelta(-30)`, for instance.