# Filter older than ...day In django?

Tags: django

```
def get_filter_result(self, customer_type='',last_contact_filled='', tag_selected='', city_selected=''):
        qdict = {}
        if customer_type != '':
            qdict['type__name'] = customer_type
            qdict['active']=True
        #MY PROBLEM IS HERE get result that older than last_contact_filled day(s)
        if last_contact_filled != '':
            for day_filter in xrange(1,int(last_contact_filled)+1):
                qdict['last_contact__day']=day_filter
            #qdict['last_contact']=last_contact_query
        if tag_selected != '':
            idtag = tag_selected.split(',')
            qdict['tag__id__in']=idtag
        if city_selected != '':
            idcity = city_selected.split(',')
            qdict['city__id__in']=idcity
        queryset = Customer.objects.filter(**qdict)
```

last_contact_filled  in the value input from user .

```
last_contact = forms.IntegerField(widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': '2'}),help_text='day(s)')
```

for example if user input 33 will get the results that last_contact older than 33 day(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984047/django-filter-older-than-days/1984055#1984055). Just modify the `timedelta()` argument appropriately.

Comment: I am sorry Ignacio Vazquez-Abran I don't understand what you want me to do ? :)

Comment: Look at my method there no no datetime.now() + timedelta(-30), for instance. my method is got the number of day(s) and filter to get the results that older than the input day(s).

Comment: Hope you will give me more details on this.
BTW thanks for your keep track.:)