# DateTimeField get all objects older than 48 hours

Tags: django

I am trying to find a straight forward way of doing filer based queries based on a datetimefiled. I have tried things like

```
timeDiff = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc) - latest_order.date
days = timeDiff.days
if days <= 2:
```

but it always gives me `RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive date time` warning. Is there a better way of exciting these queries? How can I do for instance, filer and select all objects that were created more than 48 hours ago?

Would something like this will be the correct way of doing it?

```
example = Example_Request.objects.filter(date_created__gte=datetime.datetime.today()-datetime.timedelta(days=2))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the query you posted is the correct way of doing it. However, if you want to get objects created more than 48 hours ago, you'll want to change it to `date_created__lte`. Also, you can pass in hours into a `timedelta`. For example: `datetime.timedelta(hours=48)`.

Relevant links:

- [Django filter older amount of days](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1984793/3096768)
- [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)
- [Django field lookups: `gt`, `gte`, `lt`, `lte`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#gt)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the naive date time warning, you may want to switch out:

```
datetime.now()
```

for:

```
timezone.now()
```