# Django - Filter objects older than X days

Tags: python, django

I need to filter objects older than `X` number of days. I realize this question exists here: [django filter older than day(s)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984047/django-filter-older-than-days)

However, I not trying to do exactly that, since the number of days, in my case lives inside the model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    plan = models.ForeignKey(Plan) # This model has the number of days
```

This is the query I have so far:

**EDIT**: I changed the days.plan part for `the_post.plan.days` Meaning that the number of days that I'm using to compare is in each post's `plan` field.

```
    Post.objects.filter(createdAt__lte=datetime.now() - timedelta(days=the_post.plan.days))
```

Note the `plan.days` part of the query. How can I reference `the_post.plan.days` for this query? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a small tweak in your Plan model, it is indeed possible to do what you want.

First of all, you'll need to change your Plan `days` field, which is probably an `IntegerField`, to [DurationField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#durationfield).

Now the catch is that we have to use [ExpressionWrapper](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.ExpressionWrapper) to achieve the exact same result inside Postgres as the result you'd achieve in Python if you were to get the plan in a separate query.

Finally, your query should be something like:

```
from django.db.models import F, ExpressionWrapper, DateTimeField
from django.utils import timezone

Post.objects.annotate(target_date=ExpressionWrapper(timezone.now() - F('plan__days'), output_field=DateTimeField())).filter(createdAt__lte=F('target_date'))
```

Comment: Hey @lucasnadalutti This seems like the right answer, however, I'm getting this error back: `ValueError: Not naive datetime (tzinfo is already set)` not sure why

Comment: Try replacing `datetime.now()` with `timezone.now()`, being it imported with `from django.utils import timezone`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Postgres database:

```
table_post = Post._meta.db_table
table_plan = Plan._meta.db_table

old_posts = Post.objects.select_related('plan')\
            .extra(where=["%s.created_at <= NOW() - INTERVAL '1 day' * %s.days"
                          % (table_post, table_plan)])
```

Answer (score 0):

For me you must first grab the plan object.

```
plan = Plan.objects.filter(...)
```

and then reference the days

```
 Post.objects.filter(createdAt__lte=datetime.now() - timedelta(days=plan.days))
```

Comment: How is this any different from what the question contains?

Comment: The plan in the Post model is reference to another table so it couldn't know what are the days.
in the example i first get the plan I need, and in plan variable are the days variable (for example 3). Then you can find the posts for the given plan you need.

Comment: That is already what the question is doing; `plan.days` would otherwise have read `Post.plan.days` (which is an AttributeError) or similar.

Comment: Isn't there a way in which I don't have to get the plan object in a separate query? I mean, It is already there in the post.

Comment: If you have the play object your query should work. Does Plan object contain days field as integers

Comment: yes, it does. But I get a `NameError: global name 'plan' is not defined`

Comment: Could you provide the whole function/method to analize plan variable?